# Cloning javascript object that includes functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm coding a javascript graphic game with different shapes, a kind of guess the shape. Each a different combination of smaller shapes. The shapemodel constructor is color with 3 different methods, all functions that call various drawing code. I've copied how the list is created.

```
    var shapeList = [];
    var shapeArray = [
            new shapeModel("#ff0", FShape1, circleSegment, miscShape1),
            new shapeModel("#f00", FShape1, circleHollow, miscShape1),
            new shapeModel("#000", FShape1, circleSegment, miscShape2),
            new shapeModel("#08f", FShape2, circleSegment, miscShape1),
            new shapeModel("#060", FShape2, circleHollow, miscShape1),
            new shapeModel("#007", FShape2, circleSegment, miscShape2),
            new shapeModel("#0f7", FShape1, circleHollow, miscShape2),
            new shapeModel("#888", FShape2, circleHollow, miscShape2)
        ];
    
    shapeArray.forEach(function (value, index) {

        shapeList.push(value);
    });
    
    function shapeModel(c, fshape, circle, misc) {
    
        var newElement = {
            shapeColour: c,
            startX: 200,
            startY: 200,
            thickness: 6,

            fullShape: function () {
                fshape(this);
                circle(this);
                misc(this);
            }
        }
    
        return newElement;
    }
```

My problem is copying this whole list to a new list by value not reference which will then randomly choose 1 of the 8 bigger shapes, without interfering with the original list.

```
var tempList = shapeList.slice(0);
```

does not create an independent list but at least copies all elements

```
var tempList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shapeList));
```

does not copy the functions and leaves them 'undefined'. There is probably umpteen parsing and stringing hacks but it gets quite messy.

Can I actually do this with functions or do I need to rethink the whole structure?

Comment: As a headsup - it's not *just* functions you lose, you're also losing the whole prototype of your objects.

Comment: Instead of having a master list (`shapeArray`), why not a function that creates that array like that and returns it? Then you can call that function again when you need a "copy"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this here is the following:

Convert `shapeModel` to a class. Or closer to a class. It's already a constructor function you call with `new`, so you may as well use prototype inheritance and make your life easier.

1. Name it `ShapeModel` with a capital `S`. It's the accepted convention for constructor functions.
2. Assign all the constructor parameters you get to `this`, so you can re-use them later.
3. Move the `fullShape` method to the prototype. As an advantage, you don't need one `fullShape` function for every single `ShapeModel` you create - there is only one in memory and all `ShapeModel`s share it. If you have many of these, it would reduce the memory footprint.
4. Add a `.clone()` method so you can create a new instance from an old one. This way it's easy to maintain the logic for how to clone stuff and you don't need to figure a super generic cloning mechanism that would be hard to fit if all you really need is to clone one type of objects anyway.

Once that is done, you have a simple and reusable constructor function. Since you can just take any object and call `.clone()` on it, the way to make a copy is trivial:

```js
shapeArray.map(function(model) {
  return model.clone();
});
```

And here is how the whole thing would look like:

```js
function ShapeModel(c, fshape, circle, misc) {
  this.shapeColour = c;
  this.fshape = fshape;
  this.circle = circle;
  this.misc = misc;

  this.startX = 200;
  this.startY = 200;
  this.thickness = 6;

  return newElement;
}

ShapeModel.prototype.fullShape = function() {
  this.fshape(this);
  this.circle(this);
  this.misc(this);
}

ShapeModel.prototype.clone = function() {
  return new ShapeModel(this.shapeColour, this.fshape, this.circle, this.misc);
}

var shapeArray = [
  new ShapeModel("#ff0", FShape1, circleSegment, miscShape1),
  new ShapeModel("#f00", FShape1, circleHollow, miscShape1),
  new ShapeModel("#000", FShape1, circleSegment, miscShape2),
  new ShapeModel("#08f", FShape2, circleSegment, miscShape1),
  new ShapeModel("#060", FShape2, circleHollow, miscShape1),
  new ShapeModel("#007", FShape2, circleSegment, miscShape2),
  new ShapeModel("#0f7", FShape1, circleHollow, miscShape2),
  new ShapeModel("#888", FShape2, circleHollow, miscShape2)
];


var shapeList = shapeArray.map(function(model) {
  return model.clone;
});
```